# How to put this script inside the onclick function?

Tags: javascript

I run this script by clicking the button by ID. I want to use the onclick function to run this script not working.

```
<button id="rzp-button1" onclick=ShowCal()>Pay</button>
```

I have an onclick function to call this script is not working, please help

```
<script>

function ShowCal() {

    var options = {



        "key": "rzp_test_jzLFENHc7oM",
        "amount": "<%=Session["payment"]%>", /// The amount is shown in currency subunits. Actual amount is ₹599.
        "name": "New tech",
        "order_id": "<%=Session["orderId"]%>", // Pass the order ID if you are using Razorpay Orders.
        "currency": "INR" ,// Optional. Same as the Order currency
        "description": "",
        "image": "images/new.png",
        "handler": function (response){
            alert(response.razorpay_order_id);
        },
    p1 = new Razorpay(options);

    document.getElementById('rzp-button1').onclick = function (e)

    {
        rzp1.open();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: use this: onclick="ShowCal()" and you forget close brace in end of the function "}".

Comment: Values for attributes should be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: syntax error you are using double quotes inside double quotes and miss a }

Comment: @hassan.ef I put double quotes on showcall() and use close brace still not working the page only reload

Answer (score 0):

```
function ShowCal() {
    var options = {
        "key": "rzp_test_jzLFENHc7oM",
        "amount": "<%=Session["+ payment +"]%>",
        "name": "New tech",
        "order_id": "<%=Session["+ orderId +"]%>",
        "currency": "INR",
        "description": "",
        "image": "images/new.png",
        "handler": function (response) {
            alert(response.razorpay_order_id);
        }
    }

    p1 = new Razorpay(options);    

    document.getElementById('rzp-button1').onclick = function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        rzp1.open();
    }
}
```